# Android studio make new project error

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, ide

If I click new project, the IDE Problem occurs and the error code says,

> NullPointerException: null

this code shows at event log. 
And nothing happens. How can I fix it? 
I did a solution. 
Add line to idea.properties. 
But it can't fix my problems.

here's the error code

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.PlatformTarget.getLibsFromJson(PlatformTarget.java:182)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.PlatformTarget.<init>(PlatformTarget.java:124)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargetMap(AndroidTargetManager.java:94)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargets(AndroidTargetManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.isGlassInstalled(AndroidSdkUtils.java:481)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.ConfigureFormFactorStep.populateAdditionalFormFactors(ConfigureFormFactorStep.java:99)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.ConfigureFormFactorStep.<init>(ConfigureFormFactorStep.java:67)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.deprecated.ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.init(ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:98)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:234)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.NewProjectWizardDynamic.addPaths(NewProjectWizardDynamic.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.NewProjectWizardDynamic.init(NewProjectWizardDynamic.java:86)
at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.java:63)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:197)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:156)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:211)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$2(ActionMenuItem.java:304)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:905)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:284)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$300(TransactionGuardImpl.java:40)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:123)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:109)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: did you tried to reinstall?

Comment: Yes.. i reinstalled 3 times but nothing changed

Comment: do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: Yes. I just install android studio.

Comment: this is crasy :/

Comment: I  solve this problem! I reinstall my stutio ver. 2.3 -> 2.23

Comment: Also my computer have some problems and i went hospital , they said that my memory is broken so you need to change motherboard. I buy this laptop just 3days ago.. I'll reinstall 2.23 ver with this problem solved laptop :)